# Range of divergence operator on the space of traceless symmetric $(0,2)$ tensors; conformal vector fields on an arbitrary metric on $S^2$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-operators, conformal-geometry, geometric-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a metric on $S^2$.
I am trying to solve the following PDE on a $(0,2)$ symmetric traceless tensor $A$:
$$div_{\gamma} A = \omega$$
where $\omega$ is a 1-form.

It is known that there exists a unique solution if and only if $\omega$ is $L^2$ orthogonal to conformal killing (CK) vector fields on $(S^2,\gamma)$ (the Lie algebra of the conformal group of $S^2$).

It is also known that if $\gamma$ is the round sphere, then the space of CK vector fields is a 6-dim space.

If $\gamma$ is not the round metric, what can we say about the space of CK vector fields? Will it also be 6-dimensional? I think that if $\gamma$ is of negative curvature, then it won't admit any CK vector fields and so the divergence operator is an isomorphism onto the space of 1-forms. What about if $\gamma$ is of positive curvature?

Using the uniformization theorem, we know there exists an $f$ (in a 3-dimensional space I think?) such that $\gamma = f^2 \gamma_0$ where $\gamma_0$ is the round sphere, and so $div_{\gamma} = \frac{1}{f^2} div_{\gamma_0}$. So we need $f^2 \omega$ to be $L^2$ orthogonal to conformal killing vector fields on the round sphere. Can we utilize the freedom of choosing $f$ to figure out precisely which $\omega$ will work?

It seems to me that for any CK vector field $X$ with respect to $\gamma_0$, we have $\mathcal{L}_X \gamma = f^2 \mathcal{L}_X \gamma_0 + X(f^2) \gamma_0 = (h + \frac{X(f^2)}{f^2})\gamma$ where $h$ satisfies $\mathcal{L}_X \gamma_0 = h \gamma_0$. So $X$ is CK with respect to $\gamma$ also. But that seems to say that the space of CK vector fields doesn't depend on the metric. That must be wrong because $\gamma$ might be of negative curvature, which doesn't admit CK vector fields. What am I doing wrong? (There is probably something fundamental that I am not understanding).

Any help or references is appreciated.

Comment: Conformal Killing vector fields are the same for any two conformal metrics. Any two metrics on the sphere are conformal up to diffeomorphism (by the uniformization theorem for Riemann surfaces). So the conformal Killing fields are identified by that diffeomorphism.

Comment: Oh so my calculation at the end was correct. I thought if the metric has negative curvature, then it doesn't admit CK vector fields. That must be wrong then. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a smooth metric on $\mathbb{S}^2$, it cannot have (globally) negative curvature by Gauss-Bonnet.

Comment: OH! that was what's wrong! Thank you @WillieWong     Do you know precisely what is the family of $f$ such that $\gamma = f^2 \gamma_0$? Is that a 3-parameter family of functions?